# discord.py erro no client.send_message(), preciso de ajuda

Tags: python

Sou bem iniciante e comecei a fazer um bot com a biblioteca discord.py, porém ao usar este código:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    canal = client.get_channel("50694371938855479491")
    mensagem = (f'============BEM VINDO AO DISCORD DA GUEEG GAMING, {member.mention}!============" \
               "\n Para me chamar basta escrever "Oi Krienza" ou apenas "Krienza" ta ligado?'
                f'\n Zepeto Zepeturr Hhaha zomplerin')

    await message.channel.send(canal, mensagem)
```

Fiz a mudança de client.send_message para message.channel.send() que é como acabei lendo na documentação da nova versão da discord.py. Porém recebo erro como por exemplo ''Message unassigned''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei um problema parecido:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59333157/discord-py-send-message-to-channel

Fiz o seguinte teste:

```
    mensagem = (f'============BEM VINDO AO DISCORD DA GUEEG GAMING, {member.mention}!============" \
           "\n Para me chamar basta escrever "Oi Krienza" ou apenas "Krienza" ta ligado?'
            f'\n Zepeto Zepeturr Hhaha zomplerin')

    channel = bot.get_channel(725359504417357835)

    await channel.send(mensagem)
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu nem iria tentar, pois eu tinha feito algo extremamente parecido, porém fiz e realmente continuou o problema, porém foi só eu trocar em "channel = bot.get_channel(725359504417357835)" que você mandou por "channel = client.get_channel(725359504417357835)" já que o evento que criei foi pelo @client.event e nao bot e ai funcionou. Muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: Ali só foi questão de nome de variável mesmo, valeu!